# How do I turn a "random" number read from a text file into an array

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to turn a number in a text file I find with regex into a list of numbers starting with zero.

for example, the number is `4` I need to make an array that comprises of `0,1,2,3`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) as:

```
@arr = 0..$number_read_from_file - 1;
```

Comment: that simple?, I expecting more.

Comment: @Solignis: Yes, it’s indeed that simple: `@ary = 0 .. ($n‑1)` is all it takes. Remember that one of the Perl slogans is that *Easy things should be easy, and hard things should be possible.*  This falls into the former category.

Comment: I add for completeness a slightly more idiomatic version of the same (note to OP, it modifies the var in place): `@arr = 0 .. --$number_read_from_file`

Comment: I guess I was over thinking things. I took me 4 days to get the regex to work perfectly and after that I was burned out with coding. Now I got a start and hopfully I can make this stupid function I have been working on finally work. Thanks for the help.